# Running windows service as a standalone application during DEBUG mode

Tags: windows-services, console-application

I've a windows service that I need to install (installutil) every time I debug the application during development. Is there any way I can tweak the Installer/ProjectInstaller classes so that it runs as a console application during debug mode. Something like #if..#endif preprocessors can help?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but when I write services I write the "worker" part of the service as a DLL and use it from a Winform/console app.  I only use an actual service to call into the already tested and stable worker DLL.